# Construction of a graph $G$ with $\lvert V(G)\rvert = 13$ vertices and minimum degree of every vertex $\delta_0 = 3$ aiming to maximize its diameter

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, extremal-graph-theory

How would you construct a connected undirected graph $G$ to attain the longest diameter $d =\text{diam}(G)$ (i.e. the longest distance between any pairs of vertices in $G$) possible?

Parameters $G$ needs to satisfy:

- number of vertices, i.e. order $\lvert V(G)\rvert = 13$
- minimum degree of every vertex $\delta_0 = 3$ (i.e. the number of adjacent vertices of any vertex in $G$ must be $\geq 3$)

My approach was constructing segments of sub-graphs that are only connected via one edge in order to force using these and spread out the outer vertices ($A_1, A_{13}$). This gives me a maximum diameter of $d = 7$ (marked blue).

[image: graph]

Can you construct a graph with $d > 7$?
Is there a better approach constructing graphs with maximum diameter?

Edit:
I found a classical theorem due to Erdös, Pach, Pollack and Tuza (Diameter and Minimum Degree, Journal of Combinatorial Theory 47 (1989), 73-79):

[image: Erdös theorem]

[A pdf of this paper can be found here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272566/1-s2.0-S0095895600X00822/1-s2.0-009589568990066X/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEF0aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIFPRpsmn%2BUSo8YNcS7Fi4u0ehPT3CyhxTxxX8v%2Frq5hZAiEA8onTHi4WArxImWTfg86%2Fa4XsGdkFwXQfOpj8JkDDoZEqvAUI1v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDMSz9MS%2BM8SdRaQzwCqQBencOYDdAgIUt2ojx%2BVaJjZ%2BY0oa6U6vVeq7cjjWAPtSCtFijtSWxovusxmiVK63YHi5BRuJS3j9nUqHavKPkzWzxtcVwY%2FxMOsxJ8MK0tE3m2apzaVrrPRcN69NDJ0USBVHv1sK%2B4epCEc9MQwxPyjOKRnpNoGtbG49K0xyrUykgiZi77el8C8j0F99wQt2yP43%2FTGhJnU%2B0eRdy9ZvhSJXYjZ3QNNoo9AFNCPPL882hlDUOHJJBQw0eIa3iwP8UWxb50e1Dx9%2BFhNyeKb4lycad414cIQKel3JBw9AkGrpQg5xGgvlXrJJd54uyA3DyPYt4LtX4y1ZDw9AIvjpX1dqXyEawamq9pKH01XH9B4WUxdXzWjZ6TJsKxdtJFSvb7DZe1OKWn4W%2FPz6fzT4pZIvNlN373EVYN%2FsjcLSZa2eM65vW8usOlhobOKFruE9LBvgWcM25mjtrw1tf7h4S65keo7lC6lRckcN7p%2F4UAlOoT9WQgKPZ7sanZmG8xquuAZAIkl5kAJbs1R6ubNcCDO4jwXEf%2Fh04jgWgZiIEbtD9WS1eUCRmxjG%2B1C6eTtww6JAhllOKdFuVg4LjtYYcInZyoC9d1CLaa%2BrhIDFwJgKzsv8iQF9wu93OIih11Y3k5EhufsxGesB8qqbSAuPwHsPOpb6gA%2FoVhYUwEM%2Fb9RY2X6YJQixCbexe9u3UbL9DAC1Zy6c44IoL0n2MvYKchD3PEOeSc4qomCeQdDiVVFC87%2BmykZgqP25R%2FXbFLvTK6Ta9Pj%2B%2B7uxO%2FoQg2oxNOYxGhPnZwk6Jlu07t1axblEp8kOiFB2KfZX6ZeGJFvtOCfa%2F5NOUeVUltogMvBc6MrV8qFKVKpD9GttWf7N4ceNMOPFuqUGOrEBCeiKBMLul6geovppc20HwKiBGtu8lEQSOH8BcbdKNfJFrW1e8lVQfRiBTKfCXBj%2FWfoYCe6M7djIZOjgRAQAtIUtL4ZucKabPOCrA87PGbGKT9%2F4cF6s%2Frg9qUoDsIZfptexsLbzEaYVVYXFjeCuM3f0iq9uinjtobmacHscyUCmrxijf0M8nnmiirLV9l%2FEmCVTp80aYR%2F1RZi6u3AXa2MkfgkqMXe%2BrscpBhpTanBm&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230712T134614Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYX3K3C3R4%2F20230712%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7dd99420fda0fa6a0143dea535b63679c5fc9f6cf279927d56bee2223813e684&hash=a3695c3b4fb0ade97a3f992118e0438d288ba9ea4f814d098c15a10747879b31&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=009589568990066X&tid=spdf-e93357af-96bf-428e-8b15-1bab4fe17492&sid=a6b325d4693140465a0bb1a56941b4e370c6gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=00005504565d070155&rr=7e59bb2fbb5a1d8c&cc=de)

Does this imply that for my special case with $n=13$ and $\delta = 3$ the diameter $d =\text{diam}(G) \leq \left \lfloor \dfrac{3 \cdot 13}{3 + 1} \right \rfloor - 1 = 8$?
And since $\delta = 3 \leq 5$, the equality case cannot hold so $d=7$ is indeed the greatest diameter possible for this specific $G$?

Comment: Theorem doesn't state that equality can't hold for $\delta \le 5$. It states only that it can hold for $\delta > 5$ for infinitely many $n$. Statement $A \implies B$ doesn't imply $\overline A \implies \overline B$

Comment: @Smylic Thank you for your answer :) Does the theorem state that the upper bound of the maximum possible diameter is sharp? I.e. if I can construct a graph $G$ for given $n$ and $\delta$ with diameter $\text{diam}(G) = \left \lfloor \dfrac{3n}{\delta + 1} \right \rfloor - 1 $, can I conclude that $G$ reaches maximum possible diameter for these parameters $n$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Yes, if you construct such a graph $G$, then $G$ reaches maximum possible diameter for its $n$ and $\delta \ge 2$. But for some values of $n$ and $\delta$ (even for $\delta > 5$) this bound may be not sharp. For example for $n \ge 5$ and $\delta = 2$ this bound is $3n / 3 - 1 = n - 1$, while sharp bound is $n - 3$. Or for $n = \delta + 1 \ge 3$ the only such graph is $K_n$ and $\mathrm{diam}(K_n) = 1 < 2 = 3n / n - 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already commented why the theorem doesn't show that your example reaches maximum possible diameter. Here let's prove that for $n = 13$ and $\delta \ge 3$ diameter $7$ is maximum possible.

Suppose the opposite, that there is such graph with diameter at least $8$. Then it has a path $P_9$ as an induced subgraph. (This path is diameter itself.) Since $\delta \ge 3$ each of $2$ end vertices of this path should be adjacent to $2$ vertices not from the path. And also these ends can't have common neighbors, so there is a (not induced) subgraph with all $13$ vertices.

[image]

Now we can consider vertex $5$ (the same works with $4$ and $6$). It is adjacent to at least one more vertex and since $P_9$ is induced, this neighbor is one of $\{\,10, 11, 12, 13\,\}$. In any case such edge decreases distance between $1$ and $9$ down to $6$. This contradiction ends the proof.